# Caching a prototype function doesn't cache the object it belongs to

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

In Javascript I'm trying to make an array of functions to be executed by Async.series.

Javascript:

```
function Field(name, height, width) {
   this.name = name;
   this.height = height;
   this.width = width;
}

Field.prototype.doSomething = function(callback) {
   console.log(name, width, height);
   // do some stuff with name, height etc. and produce someResults
   callback(undefined, someResults
}
```

Problem:

```
// Dict of Functions
var functions = {};

// Array of Field Objects
fields.forEach( function(field) {
  functions[field.name] = field.doSomething;
}

Async.series( functions, callback );
```

The problem is that all my "class" variables aren't cached when the function is so I get exceptions when trying to run the function in Async.series (name, width and height are not defined).

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
fields.forEach( function(field) {
  functions[field.name] = field.doSomething.bind(field);
}
```

Otherwise, there is no chance that the value of `this` inside your `doSomething` is going to be what you want. Calling `bind` sets `this` to the value of `field` at the time `bind` is called.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much this is perfect!